# Redirect to index.php when other pages have been accessed

Tags: php

i have this php pages

index.php

```
<?php
    include 'viewannouncement.php';
?>
```

viewannouncement.php

```
<?php     
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT announcement_date,announcement_title,
          announcement_text FROM sp_announcement") or die(mysql_error());  

        echo "<table id=\"newspaper-b\">";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th scope=\"col\">Date</th>";
        echo "<th scope=\"col\">Title</th>";
        echo "<th scope=\"col\">Announcement</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['announcement_date'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['announcement_title'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['announcement_text'] . '</td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
?>
```

in index.php it has a tab which includes and views  viewannouncement.php, the problem is when i access the subpages manually it leaves a whitescreen, how can i make it redirect to index.php and still be view able via the tabs in index.php

i hope you guys can help me, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: @BhavinRana i think its a newbie problem but to be specific, i just dont want my sub pages to be accessed manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically people set a variable to check if a file was included or not,
Why not do something like this?
In your index file

```
<?php
$fromIndex = true;
include 'viewannouncement.php';
?>
```

Then in your file viewannouncement.php, try this at the top.

```
if(!isset($fromIndex)) {
  header('Location: /index.php');
  die;
}
```